# Plot contour plot with label but witout dots

Tags: contour

I have to plot contour plots in **gnuplot** with labels but without dots. I tried several steps to avoid dots in my plot. I want my plot with contour values in plot. For that I used splot with labels. But gnuplot plots dots in plot. **how this can be avoided**.

splot 'DM_Plot.txt' using 1:($2/1000):3,'DM_Plot.txt' using 1:($2/1000):3 with labels

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to see more of the command sequence.  It is not obvious that the dots visible in your figure come from the "splot" command.  "set grid dashtype '.'" could produce such a thing. Do you have a "set grid" command?
I would guess that the sequence of commands you need is something like

```
unset grid 
set pm3d explicit
set contours
splot 'DM_Plot.txt' using 1:($2/1000):3 with pm3d, \
      'DM_Plot.txt' using 1:($2/1000):3 with labels
```

Does that match what you tried?